# operator does not exist: integer + interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next part of query:

```
  AND date_part('day', some_date::date - first_day::date + interval '1 day') = some_daye
```

and I am getting next error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer + interval
```

How I can cast 'some_date - first_day' to interval?

Comment: @dai: yes [it is](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What data type is `some_daye`? Can you please **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected result based on that? See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtracting a `date` from a `date` yields an `integer`.

An `integer` cannot be cast to an `interval`.

Cast either of your `date` values to `timestamp` to get an `interval`.

e.g. `AND date_part('day', some_date::timestamp - first_day + interval '1 day') = some_daye`

Or you could simplify the entire expression as `AND some_date - first_day + 1 = some_daye`